# Swimmer plot to follow pacients treatments using dates

Tags: r, ggplot2

Been working on a project where I have a similar dataset as the one bellow, and for longitudinal analyses, I really wanted to do a swimmer plot to track pacients' medication consumption.

I can only find swimmer plots with numeric type values on the x-axis, nothing regarding **actual dates**.

```
swim_table = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                        med = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "E", "C", "E", "B"),
                        startDate = c(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2000/01/01"), to = as.Date("2000/03/02"), by = "1 month"),
                                      seq.Date(from = as.Date("2001/01/01"), to = as.Date("2001/03/01"), by = "1 month"),
                                      seq.Date(from = as.Date("2002/01/01"), to = as.Date("2002/03/01"), by = "1 month")),
                        endDate = c(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2001/01/01"), to = as.Date("2001/03/02"), by = "1 month"),
                                      seq.Date(from = as.Date("2002/01/01"), to = as.Date("2002/03/01"), by = "1 month"),
                                      seq.Date(from = as.Date("2003/01/01"), to = as.Date("2003/03/01"), by = "1 month")))

swimmer_plot(df=swimmer_graph_data,id='id',name_fill='med',col=1) +
  theme_bw()

swimmer_plot(df=swim_table ,id='id',name_fill="med",col=1,
             start = 'startDate', end = 'endDate',
             id_order = c('1', '2', '3')) +theme_bw()
```

I've tried to solve the error by doing (it has worked in the past)

```
swim_table$startDate = format(as.Date(swim_table$startDate, format="Y/%m/%d"),"%d/%m/%Y")
```

It still doesn't plot, and by doing

```
swim_table$endDate = format(as.Date(swim_table$endDate, format="Y/%m/%d"),"%d/%m/%Y")
```

I get an even more confusing error.
Can anyone please take a look at this?

Comment: What error messages you are getting? What package does the `swimmer_plot` function come from?

Comment: I should have said the package, you're right. It's from `library(swimplot)` (and `ggplot2` also).
Firstly I get: `Error in as.Date.default(value) : do not know how to convert 'value' to class “Date”`
And then in the last attempt I get;
`Error in df[, end] - stats::ave(df[, end], df[, id], FUN = dplyr::lag) : non-numeric argument to binary operator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using dates does seem to break `swimmer_plot`. However, there is a way round it. Convert your dates to numbers using `as.numeric`, draw the plot, then change the axis labels from numbers back to dates.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(swimplot)

swim_table$startDate <- as.numeric(swim_table$startDate)
swim_table$endDate   <- as.numeric(swim_table$endDate)

swimmer_plot(df=swim_table ,id='id',name_fill="med",col=1,
             start = 'startDate', end = 'endDate',
             id_order = c('1', '2', '3')) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) as.Date(as.numeric(x), origin = "1970-01-01")) +
  coord_flip(ylim = c(min(swim_table$startDate), max(swim_table$endDate))) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I wanted. Now I have another "problem", it's what to do when I have people taking more than one medication at a time.

Comment: Also, why the `origin = "1970-01-01"`? Just wondering :)

Comment: @Leonor I don't think there is any special reason other than that was a conveniently 'round' number a few years before most of the main programming languages and operating systems were created.